# Image Slideshow in js hanging app

Tags: javascript

I have written this method in javascript:

```
function displayImage() {

   window.setInterval(function(){
       for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
           document.getElementById("img1").setAttribute("src",
                   "images/th-" + i + ".jpg");
           if(i==4){
               i=0;
           }
       }
   }, 3000);     
}
```

and am calling this method from html page: . But after 3 sec, my application hangs and nothing happens. What is going wrong in this?

Answer (score 2):

In this case your `for` loop will work 4 times after every `3000` milliseconds. You need to change one picture after each `3000` milliseconds.

Try this

```
function displayImage() {

   var img = document.getElementById("img1");
   var imgIndex = 1;

   window.setInterval(function(){
       img.setAttribute("src", "images/th-" + imgIndex + ".jpg");
       imgIndex = imgIndex === 3 ? 0 : imgIndex + 1;
   }, 3000);
}
```